# ri5cy disable interrupts at core level

Tags: c, assembly, riscv, riscv32

In ri5cy [documentation](https://www.pulp-platform.org/docs/ri5cy_user_manual.pdf), it says that :

> [§12.1 Interrupts] Interrupts can only be enabled/disabled on a global basis and not individually. It is assumed that there is an
> event/interrupt controller outside of the core that performs masking and buffering of the interrupt lines. The **global
> interrupt enable is done via the CSR register MSTATUS**.

but actually, there is nothing in the MSTATUS register § about this, the only thing close is:

> [§MSTATUS.MIE] "Machine Interrupt Enable: If you want to enable interrupt handling **in your exception handler**, set the Interrupt Enable MIE to 1’b1 inside your handler code"

ok, you can enable interrupt in your exception handler but how to enable/disable globally interrupts?

Setting/Clearing MSTATUS.MIE does not en/disable globally interrupts (IRQ are always on, even if MSTATUS.MIE = 0)

So I think there is an error in the ri5cy implementation of the riscv specs,
for instance, for cv32e40x, globally interrupts en/disable is done - at core level - through the MIE CSR, so when MIE = 0xFFFFFFFF all irqs are enabled and when MIE = 0 are irqs are disabled.

Could I disable irqs globally with ri5y?
I thought about using the event controller:

- to disable: saving the IER and setting it to 0
- to re-enable: setting back the IER to the previous saved value

but this very looks like tinkering...

Comment: The CSR registers are global, so changing them will have global effect.  However, let's also note that an interrupt and the handler's eventual `MRET` will change them too, so that's why it doing something in a handler may appears to have effect only locally, i.e. during the handler.